# Getting accurate measurements in EPSG: 27700 using QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis-3, epsg, measurements

When taking measurements in a project where all layers are EPSG:27700 (with elipsoid Airy 1830) the measurements produced are incorrect. 
Is there a better CRS for distance measurements in the UK? Or is there something I can check in the project set up?

[image: Measurement out by 60m]

[image: Elipsoid measurement]

[image: Measurement checked on google and also verified on OS maps]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use the `Cartesian` checkbox as OSGB is a cartesian projection. The calculation in EPSG:27700 is more likely to be the correct one - you don't say what your "standard" is.

Here is a check I carried out using OS master map and Worthing Pier (293m long according to Wikipedia). Switching to ellipsoidal gave 294.063m so I suspect there is something wrong with your setup somewhere.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. With reference to the 'standard' do you mean where I checked what the measurement should be?   If so I checked it in google maps (image of measurement included in question) and on OS maps online (both showed 90m not 150m). Aditionally I did check some other distances to confirm but did not include images to avoid clutter.

Comment: if those were in epsg:3857 then they were probably wrong - can you give us a location where you are testing?

Comment: The location is in Kingston upon Hull, All layers and the map canvas are in EPSG 27700

Comment: thay are in 3857 if you are using google imagery as your base map, quick maps reprojects your project when it is added

Comment: The base map has been converted to 27700. I tried using the base map in 3857 with OTF on, and converting the map to 27700 with the same results.

Comment: AFAIK you can not reproject the Google Base maps no matter what the CRS box says